# Push notification to app group iOS

Tags: objective-c, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I would like to send a single push notification to an app group which contains 2 apps. Is this possible using a single push certificate meant for a group ?

Comment: I thought it did not possible as both apps have different "Bundle Identifier".

Comment: similar to how UserDefaults can be shared across 2 apps in a group, may be Apple has devised some strategy to send a push targeted at a group rather than app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you have to create individual push certificate for individual application.